# Using Windows Command Line To Rename Folders

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-7

I have a group of folders two levels deep, like:

```
Folder A
    Sub Folder A – 1
        <Files>
    Sub Folder A – 2
        <Files>
Folder B
    Sub Folder B – 1
        <Files>
Folder C
    Sub Folder C – 1
        <Files>
    Sub Folder C – 2
        <Files>
    Sub Folder C – 3
        <Files>
```

I need to use Windows 7 CommandLine or Powershell to rename the sub folders so that it includes the parent folder's name in it, like

```
Sub Folder A - 1
```

would be renamed to

```
Folder A - Sub Folder A - 1
```

Possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do it for you.

```
$RootDirectory = 'c:\test';

# 1. Get list of parent folders
$ParentFolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootDirectory -Directory;

# 2. Iterate over top-level folders
foreach ($ParentFolder in $ParentFolderList) {
    $ChildFolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentFolder.FullName

    # 3. Iterate over subfolders of top-level folders, and rename them
    foreach ($ChildFolder in $ChildFolderList) {
        $NewFolderName = '{0}\{1} - {2}' -f $ParentFolder.FullName, $ParentFolder.Name, $ChildFolder.Name;
        Rename-Item -Path $ChildFolder.FullName -NewName $NewFolderName -WhatIf;
    }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet to have it make the changes.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm getting on error on the second line saying "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'."  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably running PowerShell v2. You can upgrade Windows 7 to 4.0! 1) Install .NET Framework 4.5.1, and then 2) install the Windows Management Framework Core 4.0 package.

Comment: Actually got it.  Stupid user error.  I'm new to PS.  I had pasted that into the Powershell window.  For whatever reason it didn't like it.  When I turned it into a .PS1 file and ran that, it worked perfect.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad to hear it, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can run this as a bat on the command prompt

```
for /d %%i in (*) do (
     for /d %%x in ("%%i/*") do ren "%%i/%%x" "%%i - %%x"
)
```